# Dummy partition for grand total

Tags: sql, impala

fellow developers and analysts

I have a seemingly simple question where I would like to sum with a group by but ALSO a column which displays the grand total, i.e. same numerical value for each row. The caveat is that I do not want to use any join.

I am thinking some sort of dummy partition:

```
SELECT     Region
          ,sum(sales)
          ,sum(sales) OVER (partition by)
FROM      table
GROUP BY  1
```

but, of course, this did not work. I am using Impala. I hope you can help me with this. Look forward to your replies.

Answer (score 0):

Just Increase the scope of the summary function (don't partition)

```
SELECT *
        ,SUM([EXAMPLE]) OVER(PARTITION BY FOO ORDER BY BAR DESC) AS [TOTAL]
        ,SUM([EXAMPLE]) OVER() AS [Grand_Total]
            FROM ...
```

Comment: Sorry for the belated reply. I gave the suggested answer a try and was presented with:
select list expression not produced by aggregation output (missing from GROUP BY clause?): sum(revenue) OVER ()